# How Can I Solve Following Error at Ionic Framework? " Property 'unpaid' does not exist on type 'string'. "

Tags: ionic-framework

JSON Input:

```
let url = this.common.apiURLs+"/sapp/viewq?id="+questionId+"&user_id="+val+"&format=json";
```

**Follows:** [JSON Data Link](https://api.myjson.com/bins/183uvn)

**Coding:**

```
public mykey: any;

public allData: Array<string> = [];

public userId : any;

public qid : any;

public answerId: any;

public doctorId: any;

public rating: any;

public headers:any;

public ratStar:any;

public feedback:any;

public speciality:any;

public submitQid:any;

public unpaidFree: any;

public queryStatus: any;

public maxKey: any;

constructor(public common: CommonProvider, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public fb: FormBuilder, public http: Http, private storage: Storage, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public toastCtrl: ToastController, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

/* Get From Another page */

this.qid = navParams.get('questionId');

this.queryStatus = navParams.get('qstatus');

this.viewQuery(this.qid).then(data => {

this.allData = data;

this.mykey = Object.keys(data);

this.mykey.forEach((key: any) => {

this.maxKey = key;

});

if(this.queryStatus=='unpaid'){

this.unpaidFree = this.allData[this.maxKey].unpaid['fee'];

console.log("Unpaid Free : "+this.unpaidFree);

}

});

}

/* View Query Api Call*/

viewQuery(questionId): Promise<any> {

return new Promise((resolve) => { this.storage.get('id').then((val) => {

let url = this.common.apiURLs+"/sapp/viewq?id="+questionId+"&user_id="+val+"&format=json";

this.http.get(url)

.map(res => res.json())

.subscribe(data => {

resolve(data);

});

});

});

}
```

**I Got Error Following Line:**

```
this.unpaidFree = this.allData[this.maxKey].unpaid['fee'];
```

Please Explain Me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to get fee data from your JSON:

```
var lastObject = this.allData[this.maxKey];
var unpaid = lastObject['unpaid'];
this.unpaidFree = unpaid['fee'];
```

Use this to get your value from JSON, Hope this will helps.

Comment: It code is working fine me. thank you for your help.

Comment: if above code is working for you please accept this answer so other can find it as useful and approved answer on SO.